# Why is my net vote count off by ~250?

Tags: support, voting

On my profile under the "*Activity*" tab it says I have:

```
1,164 votes cast
```

[image: Votes]

When I click onto the link to see all the votes, it says I've only have:

```
902 Votes Cast
```

[image: 902]

Why is this so off? Obviously I thought about caching but whenever I cast a vote both counts update by +1 almost instantly, although they are still apart by around 250 and have been for a while.

Comment: maybe the top one is counting deleted post? mine is different too (819-558) but i know i've voted on question/answers that were later deleted and they don't appear in the votes tab. also would be worth noting that the link takes you to the last viewed votes list, whether that be *"all"* or *"upvote"* or *"reopen"* (my 558 is from *"all"*, if i went to *"reopen"*, went to a different tab and followed the link again i'm back at *"reopen"* with *"0 votes cast"*)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117846/274942 and links therein (this question is effectively the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259928/274942 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174653/274942).

Comment: @HDE226868 thanks for the links. I didn't think to check the Stack Exchange meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is anecdotal evidence based on me auditing my own vote tallies, but I believe that the total tally is counting the votes on deleted posts as well, whereas the drill-down does not include deleted posts.

According to my profile, I've got over 9,500 downvotes.  When I look to drill into that, I have around a third of that number.

[image]

This leads me to believe that, while you've got a lot of upvotes, some of those upvotes were on posts which were deleted.  The count is likely accurate since deleted posts are only soft-deleted (and count towards a person getting out of a post ban), but the drill-down does seem to have this data discrepancy issue with it.

Comment: Yep that seems to be correct. I've just checked mine as well and it says I've got 780 downvotes, whereas only 514 'drill-down' votes due to deleted posts. This makes sense as 384(total upvotes) + 780 = 1164. And 780 - 514 = 266 which is the difference between the two counts